# WooCommerce Cart REST Api Cannot relate cart to specific user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am developing a WooCommerce Cart REST Api using PHP laravel. Below is the code snippet for such api. When I call the **add_to_cart** function it indeed adds the product to a cart and I can see that there is a record stored at the **wp_woocommerce_sessions** table with an arbitrary session key value. But I do not know how to associate that record with a specific user so each user having his own cart record and when I call **get_cart** function or the other two functions (i.e. **remove_item** or **clear_cart**) using a specific user id it gets me the record related to that user only not an arbitrary record. What is happening right now, for example, if I called the **add_to_cart** function with a given user id, for example and id of 2, a record is stored then if I called the **get_cart** function with another user id, for example an id of 1, I still got the previously stored record that was intended to be for user 2. I hope I explained my problem well...

I tried to add the private function at the top, **set_current_user**, of the code as I thought it might help and solve the problem, however, all what it did is that is changed the session key value at the **wp_woocommerce_sessions** to be the same as the user id not an arbitrary value. In addition, I tried to check the woocommerce rest api doc. and wc_cart class doc. and finally tried to google for solution.

```
private function set_current_user(int $user_id)
    {
        $curr_user = wp_set_current_user( $user_id, '' );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id);
        do_action( 'wp_login',...array($curr_user->user_login, $curr_user));
    }

    /**
     * Get cart.
     */
    public function get_cart(int $user_id)
    {
        try {
            if (!isset($user_id)) {
                throw new \Exception("You must include user id in your request.", 400);
            }

            $this->set_current_user($user_id);

            $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

            if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() <= 0) {
                return response()->json('There are no items in the cart!', 200);
            }

            foreach ($cart as $item_key => $cart_item) {
                $_product = apply_filters('wc_cart_rest_api_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $item_key);

                // Adds the product name as a new variable.
                $cart[$item_key]['product_name'] = $_product->get_name();
            }

            return response()->json($cart, 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(
                array('status' => $e->getCode(), 'message' => $e->getMessage()), $e->getCode());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add to Cart.
     */
    public function add_to_cart(Request $request, int $user_id)
    {
        try {
            if (!isset($user_id)) {
                throw new \Exception("You must include user id in your request.", 400);
            }

            $this->set_current_user($user_id);

            $product_id = !isset($request['product_id']) ? 0 : absint($request['product_id']);
            $quantity = !isset($request['quantity']) ? 1 : absint($request['quantity']);
            $cart_item_data = !isset($request['cart_item_data']) ? array() : $request['cart_item_data'];

            $this->validate_product($product_id, $quantity);

            $product_data = wc_get_product($product_id);

            if (!$product_data || 'trash' === $product_data->get_status()) {
                throw new \Exception('Warning: This product does not exist!', 400);
            }


            $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id($product_data->get_id());
            $found_in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart($product_cart_id);

            // check for existing item in cart.
            if ($found_in_cart) {
                throw new \Exception(sprintf('You cannot add another "%s" to your cart.', $product_data->get_name()), 400);
            }

            // Add item to cart.
            $item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, 0, array(), $cart_item_data);

            // Return response to added item to cart or return error.
            if ($item_key) {
                $data = WC()->cart->get_cart_item($item_key);

                do_action('wc_cart_rest_add_to_cart', $item_key, $data);

                if (is_array($data)) {
                    return response()->json($data, 200);
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Exception(sprintf('You cannot add "%s" to your cart.', $product_data->get_name()), 400);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(
                array('status' => $e->getCode(), 'message' => $e->getMessage()), $e->getCode());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validate product before it is added to the cart.
     */
    protected function validate_product($product_id = null, $quantity = 1)
    {
        $this->validate_product_id($product_id);

        $this->validate_quantity($quantity);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the product id argument.
     */
    protected function validate_product_id($product_id)
    {
        if ($product_id <= 0) {
            throw new \Exception('Product ID number is required!', 400);
        }

        if (!is_numeric($product_id)) {
            throw new \Exception('Product ID must be numeric!', 400);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validate the product quantity argument.
     */
    protected function validate_quantity($quantity)
    {
        if ($quantity <= 0) {
            throw new \Exception('Quantity can not be zero!', 400);
        }

        if (!is_numeric($quantity)) {
            throw new \Exception('Quantity must be numeric!', 400);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove Item in Cart.
     */
    public function remove_item(Request $request, int $user_id)
    {
        try {
            if (!isset($user_id)) {
                throw new \Exception("You must include user id in your request.", 400);
            }

            $this->set_current_user($user_id);

            $cart_item_key = !isset($request['cart_item_key']) ? '0' : wc_clean($request['cart_item_key']);

            if ($cart_item_key != '0') {
                if (WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key)) {
                    return response()->json(
                        array('status' => 200, 'message' => 'Item has been removed from cart.'), 200);
                } else {
                    throw new \Exception('Unable to remove item from cart.', 400);
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Cart item key is required!', 400);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(
                array('status' => $e->getCode(), 'message' => $e->getMessage()), $e->getCode());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clear cart.
     */
    public function clear_cart(int $user_id)
    {
        try {
            if (!isset($user_id)) {
                throw new \Exception("You must include user id in your request.", 400);
            }

            $this->set_current_user($user_id);

            WC()->cart->empty_cart();
            WC()->session->set('cart', array()); // Empty the session cart data

            if (WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
                return response()->json(array('status' => 200, 'message' => 'Cart is cleared.'), 200);
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Clearing the cart failed!', 400);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(
                array('status' => $e->getCode(), 'message' => $e->getMessage()), $e->getCode());
        }
    }
```

I expect to have a cart specific for a given user based on user id and when I adding/retrieving/removing/clearing the cart those action applies to that specific user's cart, however, the actual results are not like this when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I should, using the current user id, read the meta data cart entry from the user meta table and load it to the current session and after finishing within the in memory cart object I should update the the user meta entry back...